# Problem with drop down menu in Angular Material

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu, angular-material

I have a problem with any drop down menu to pick options created dynamically with Angular - Material. For example a submenu in a menu, or a selection in a mat-paginator.

[image: error pagination]

As you see, the numbers appears in other side. In the menu that i try this days does the same, creating the submenus in the wrong place, and when you click another option of the menu, Angular continues creating more submenus without deleting the others.

I am newbie in Angular, and dont know what is happening.

No error in the code. And the Table or the Menu of Material Api is good created in the navigator (and can interactuate with them).

Perhaps some CSS?

Versions:

```
Angular CLI: 9.1.13
Node: 10.20.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 9.1.13
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.901.13
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.901.13
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.901.13
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.901.13
@angular-devkit/core              9.1.13
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.1.13
@angular/cdk                      11.1.0
@angular/material                 11.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.1.13
@schematics/angular               9.1.13
@schematics/update                0.901.13
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.8.3
webpack                           4.42.0
```

Codes:

CSS:

```
 @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

table {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .mat-form-field {
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td, th {
    width: 25%;
  }
```

Html:

```
<p>lista-aduanas works!</p>

<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  
      <!-- ID Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> ID </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.id}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Progress Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="progress">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Progress </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.progress}}% </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <!-- Color Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="color">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Color </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [style.color]="row.color"> {{row.color}} </td>
      </ng-container>
  
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
  
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';


export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

export interface UserData {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  progress: string;
  color: string;
}

/** Constants used to fill up our data base. */
const COLORS: string[] = [
  'maroon', 'red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'olive', 'green', 'purple', 'fuchsia', 'lime', 'teal',
  'aqua', 'blue', 'navy', 'black', 'gray'
];
const NAMES: string[] = [
  'Maia', 'Asher', 'Olivia', 'Atticus', 'Amelia', 'Jack', 'Charlotte', 'Theodore', 'Isla', 'Oliver',
  'Isabella', 'Jasper', 'Cora', 'Levi', 'Violet', 'Arthur', 'Mia', 'Thomas', 'Elizabeth'
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-aduanas',
  templateUrl: './lista-aduanas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-aduanas.component.css']
})
export class ListaAduanasComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['id', 'name', 'progress', 'color'];
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<UserData>;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor() { 
    // Create 100 users
    const users = Array.from({length: 100}, (_, k) => createNewUser(k + 1));

    // Assign the data to the data source for the table to render
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(users);

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}

/** Builds and returns a new User. */
function createNewUser(id: number): UserData {
  const name = NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))] + ' ' +
      NAMES[Math.round(Math.random() * (NAMES.length - 1))].charAt(0) + '.';

  return {
    id: id.toString(),
    name: name,
    progress: Math.round(Math.random() * 100).toString(),
    color: COLORS[Math.round(Math.random() * (COLORS.length - 1))]
  };
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';
import { ListaAduanasComponent } from './administracion/lista-aduanas/lista-aduanas.component';

import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {platformBrowserDynamic} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material/form-field';

import { ModuleWithProviders} from "@angular/core";
import { MAT_RIPPLE_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, MatNativeDateModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatIconRegistry } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { MatBadgeModule } from '@angular/material/badge';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
import { MatStepperModule } from '@angular/material/stepper';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatGridListModule } from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatRadioModule } from '@angular/material/radio';
import { MatRippleModule } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { MatSlideToggleModule } from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatTooltipModule } from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import { MatTreeModule } from '@angular/material/tree';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    ListaAduanasComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,

    HttpClientModule,

    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatNativeDateModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,

    MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatBadgeModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        MatButtonToggleModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
        MatChipsModule,
        MatStepperModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatGridListModule,
        MatIconModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatListModule,
        MatMenuModule,
        MatPaginatorModule,
        MatProgressBarModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatRadioModule,
        MatRippleModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatSidenavModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        MatSlideToggleModule,
        MatSnackBarModule,
        MatSortModule,
        MatTableModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        MatToolbarModule,
        MatTooltipModule,
        MatTreeModule,
        MatNativeDateModule
    
  ],
  exports: [MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatBadgeModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatChipsModule,
    MatStepperModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatGridListModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatRadioModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatSnackBarModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    MatTreeModule,
    MatNativeDateModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to downgrade `@angular/cdk` and `@angular/material` to v9.1.3.
It's not recommended to have different major versions. you're using angular 9 so all of your angular dependencies must be 9 too.